# Change Ninject to Autofac equivalent for Asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, autofac

I have next code and I would like to replace it to Autofac.
what should I do ?

```
public class NinjectKernelFactory
{
  public IKernel Create()
  {
   return LoadAssembliesIntoKernel(new StandardKernel());
  }

  private IKernel LoadAssembliesIntoKernel(IKernel kernel)
  {
    foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
     try
     {
       kernel.Load(assembly);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        //Empty Catch used because ninject have problem
        //with loading some of the Sitecore MVC assemblies.
       // Method .ToString()
     }
   }
    return kernel;
  }
}

public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{

 private IKernel _kernel;
 public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
 {
   _kernel = kernel;
 }

 public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
 {
   _kernel.Release(controller);
 }

 protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
 {
   return (IController)_kernel.Get(controllerType);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The `kernel.Load` method of *Ninject* will load all class that implement `INinjectModule` from the assembly.

The equivalent in *Autofac* is to use the `RegisterAssemblyModules` method which will load all class that implement `IModule`.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
if (HostingEnvironment.InClientBuildManager)
{
    assemblies = assemblies.Union(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                              .Cast<Assembly>())
                           .Distinct();
}

builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
```

I use `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` to avoid issue after ASP.net recycling process. See [IIS Hosted Web Application](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html#iis-hosted-web-applications) on autofac documentation for more explanation.